# Is it “Macaroni, cheese, and steak” or “Macaroni and cheese and steak”?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, lists, coordinating-conjunctions

I want to list two things: "macaroni and cheese" and "steak". It should be clear that "macaroni and cheese" is one item.

Because "macaroni and cheese" has a conjunction in it and is used in a list, should a comma replace the conjunction, or should the conjunction stay?

In other words, is it

> Macaroni, cheese, and steak

or

> Macaroni and cheese and steak

?

Comment: Steak with mac & cheese. Sidestep the issue entirely.

Comment: This has been answered here before, but I can't find the thread. A and {B and C} may be rendered eg << macaroni, and cheese and steak >> or  << macaroni and cheese & steak >>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

'Macaroni and cheese' can be a set phrase for a set dish or it can be two separate things.

If you are having two things, macaroni and cheese (a single dish) and another dish (steak) then you'd say 'Macaroni and cheese, and steak'.

But if you are having three separate things, macaroni (the pasta) and also a steak (the meat) and some cheese (maybe as a separate course, maybe sprinkled on top of everything, maybe as a melted condiment to pour on you steak) then you'd have 'macaroni, cheese, and steak'

Comment: In all cases, though, you'd be unlikely to mention the steak last, since that is generally considered the main part of the course/dish.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sure, I just wanted to make sure that the reader ould understand 'macaroni and cheese' can be interpreted in two different ways, as one dish and as two separate things.

Comment: 3 separate things: It would be "cheese sauce" if it was supposed be a condiment. As a side dish (very unusual), then it would be "steak, pasta with some cheese"

Comment: @Mari-LouA good real world context points all around, but I was just trying to address the grammatical motivated punctuation question

Comment: In the US, it's "macaroni and cheese" as a side dish and you would only call it "pasta with cheese sauce" if you were going for a more high faluting sound...which you'd probably be called out for. FWIW, it's also typical (here in the US) to name the protein first so it would be "steak with macaroni and cheese" as @JanusBahsJacquet described in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

In British English the name of the dish is *macaroni cheese*, so you'd have "steak and macaroni cheese" (though the combination isn't common here).  As one accompanies the other, *with* is useful: "macaroni and cheese with steak" or better still "steak with macaroni and cheese".  That could still be misconstrued as steak plus plain macaroni plus cheese, but that would be unusual.